# Remove Transparent Borders GIMP

Tags: images, gimp, editing, transparency, space

I have an image of the Cosmic Cliffs (JWST) and I'd like to remove the transparent side borders.  How can I do this?

I had already tried to box select the image I wanted > Paste to New Layer > Delete old layer ... but nothing changes and I still see the borders.

Answer (score 0):

First:
Gimp:Menu > Image > Flatten Image
Then crop the image.

Comment: Great thank you!  Could you kindly upvote my question?  I'd like to post more questions with images but I need 15 reputation.